# How do I convert a java object toJSON format without using any external libraries or dependencies for java?

Tags: java, json, api

```
static class DataObject {
    private String access;
    private String foo;
    private Int age;
}
```

to `{"access" : "value","foo":"value","age":"value"}`

without using Gson or jackson. just vanilla java

Is there a more simpler way ?

Comment: Simpler way? No. You'd have to either do what @Reilas answered, or write a JSON serializer yourself. Your best, "simplest" way to do this is to use a library.

Comment: Please fix the compilation error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this dynamically would most-likely require recursion and, I guess reflection, also.

A simple implementation, for static content, would be to utilize the *toString* method.

Here is an example, given the data you provided within the comments.
The *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class, here, is simply an extenstion to the *[String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))* methods.
It has no correlation to *JSON* parsing, in-particularly.

```java
class DataObject {
    String aPid;
    String location;
    String senderDomainId;
    String timeZone;
    String senderDomainAgentId;
    String recipientDomainName;
    BusinessMsg businessMsg;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter(string);
        formatter.format("{%n");
        formatter.format("\"sendParams\": {".indent(4), aPid);
        formatter.format("\"aPid\": \"%s\",".indent(8), aPid);
        formatter.format("\"location\": \"%s\",".indent(8), location);
        formatter.format("\"senderDomainId\": \"%s\",".indent(8), senderDomainId);
        formatter.format("\"timeZone\": \"%s\",".indent(8), timeZone);
        formatter.format("\"senderDomainAgentId\": \"%s\",".indent(8), senderDomainAgentId);
        formatter.format("\"recipientDomainName\": \"%s\",".indent(8), recipientDomainName);
        formatter.format("\"businessMsg\": %s".indent(8), businessMsg);
        formatter.format("}".indent(4));
        formatter.format("}");
        formatter.flush();
        return string.toString();
    }

    static class BusinessMsg {
        String id, to, from;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            Formatter formatter = new Formatter(string);
            formatter.format("{%n");
            formatter.format("\"id\": \"%s\",".indent(12), id);
            formatter.format("\"to\": \"%s\",".indent(12), to);
            formatter.format("\"from\": \"%s\"".indent(12), from);
            formatter.format("}".indent(8).stripTrailing());
            formatter.flush();
            return string.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if we populate the data, and use a *println* call, we'll get a valid *JSON* value.

```java
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.aPid = "AGNT8935i";
dataObject.location = "New York";
dataObject.senderDomainId = "DOMN67";
dataObject.timeZone = "Eastern Standard Time";
dataObject.senderDomainAgentId = "DMNAGNT94-eoi7436ur-334kjery3-oe73573ne";
dataObject.recipientDomainName = "tic.com";
DataObject.BusinessMsg businessMsg = new DataObject.BusinessMsg();
businessMsg.id = "BSMG227e0e9f-2af9-4f49-8886-39eadda4d8f3";
businessMsg.to = "tic.com";
businessMsg.from = "tic.com";
dataObject.businessMsg = businessMsg;

System.out.println(dataObject);
```

Output

```
{
    "sendParams": {
        "aPid": "AGNT8935i",
        "location": "New York",
        "senderDomainId": "DOMN67",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
        "senderDomainAgentId": "DMNAGNT94-eoi7436ur-334kjery3-oe73573ne",
        "recipientDomainName": "tic.com",
        "businessMsg": {
            "id": "BSMG227e0e9f-2af9-4f49-8886-39eadda4d8f3",
            "to": "tic.com",
            "from": "tic.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you're saying that the field names, the class variables, will be dynamic?  You can use _[reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)_ to capture the values.  I could write an example if this is what you're implying.

Comment: thank you for the solution given, what if the data is dynamic with also nested objects like {"sendParams":{"aPid":"AGNT8935i", 
"location":"New York",
"senderDomainId":"DOMN67",
 "timeZone":"Eastern Standard Time",
 "senderDomainAgentId":"DMNAGNT94-eoi7436ur-334kjery3-oe73573ne",
 "recipientDomainName":"tic.com",
 "businessMsg":{id":"BSMG227e0e9f-2af9-4f49-8886-39eadda4d8f3","to:"tic.com","from":"tic.com"}}
}

Comment: If the field names will always be the same, then you can just use the same method I provided.  I can format it for you.  One minute.

Comment: this was super helpful thank you soo much, I need to add the sendParams as part of the JSON to complete it.

Comment: @edwardacholonu, my mistake, I completely overlooked that

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 20, there is still no included JSON API in the JRE.

So, your answer would be to write the String yourself, using `String.format`, for example

Regarding your class structure, you can use [records](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/records-come-to-java).